# pygame installed through homebrew does not work?

Tags: macos, homebrew, python

I ran `brew install pygame`, it installed it together with all the dependencies. Python v2.7.10 / OS X version 10.11.2

Whenever I `import pygame` in a script it says this

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "~/Documents/test.py", line 1, in <module>
import pygame, random, sys
ImportError: No module named pygame
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you checked which python are you running - the system python or the one you installed via homebrew?  I suspect the first.

As a test, try running

```
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10/bin/python
```

and typing

```
>> import pygame
```

If this works, you can make the brew version the default by using:

```
brew link python
```

Comment: I hadn't even installed it through homebrew, I didn't see any such requirements when reading about it. But thanks!

Comment: If you're going to install pygame through homebrew, using the homebrew python as well simplifies your life and setup effort greatly.

Answer (score 1):

After installing `brew install pygame` myself, it spit out this message:

```
==> python -c import setuptools... --no-user-cfg install --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/pygame/1.9.2a0 --single-version-externally-managed --record=installed.txt
==> Caveats
Python modules have been installed and Homebrew's site-packages is not
in your Python sys.path, so you will not be able to import the modules
this formula installed. If you plan to develop with these modules,
please run:
  mkdir -p /Users/packrd/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages
  echo 'import site; site.addsitedir("/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages")' >> /Users/packrd/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/homebrew.pth
```

which apparently meant "we installed this, but your python won't be able to use it"

The oddness here appears to be that if you do `brew install pygame` it doesn't install python, just pygame (for dependencies to use?)

So either follow those directions (as printed on your screen) then it works, or do `brew install python` and use that python instead (/usr/local/bin/python instead of /usr/bin/python).