# Trouble Installing Pygame on Mac - error code 255 in None

Tags: macos, mac, python

I need to install pygame on my MacBook for a class, I was able to get it installed fine on my Windows machine, but the OSX installation process has been much rougher. The error I'm getting when try and clone the mercurial repository:

```
pip3 install hg+bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame
Command "hg clone --noupdate -q http://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame /var/folders/97/gp7g9lv51w92vlqkbskfx55c0000gn/T/pip-zu8qunw4-build" failed with error code 255 in None
```

Also all of the other steps in the installation worked fine and Mercurial is properly installed.

Comment: Does that directory exist (and why use such an odd one)

Comment: If you don't need to use `hg` you might have better luck with https://brew.sh on OS X - see http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/222333/pygame-installed-through-homebrew-does-not-work

Comment: @Mark I didn't specify a directory, I simply used the command: pip3 install hg+http://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. It's best to use the edit command to fix your post so that it reads correctly when additional data will help us try to help you.

Comment: @bmike Thank you very much for the reply, that worked perfectly!

Comment: Jackson - I've got plenty of rep - want to add an answer and then accept it once the grace period expires? Your words and solution will help others looking to solve pip errors :-)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Using brew and not hg fixed the problem, I used this line for installation:

```
brew install homebrew/python/pygame
```